# Issue with AllowHTML not allowing html to be passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC5 application. I'm trying to send some HTML code via textarea. I decorated my model with [AllowHtml] yet it still pops this error:

> ASP.NET detected potentially dangerous data in the request because it
> may include HTML tags or scripts. The data may indicate an attempt to
> compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site
> scripting attack. If the type of entry is appropriate for your
> application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow
> it.

This is my model :

```
namespace siredd_vf.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
   


    public partial class SIREDD_PRE
    {
        
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string PRETEXT { get; set; }
        
        public Nullable<int> ID_REGON { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am decorating the PRETEXT field so it acceptes the html code :

This my ActionResult in the controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,PRETEXT,ID_REGON")] SIREDD_PRE sIREDD_PRE)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                sIREDD_PRE.ID_REGON = 2;
                db.SIREDD_PRE.Add(sIREDD_PRE);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(sIREDD_PRE);
        }
```

And I'm calling this in my view :

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Présentation </label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PRETEXT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, cols = 50, rows = 10 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRETEXT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

I don't know what I'm missing? If you have an idea it would be kind from you to let me know.

Comment: `it still pops the html script` what does that html script say?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ASP.NET detected potentially dangerous data in the request because it may include HTML tags or scripts. The data may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If the type of entry is appropriate for your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it.